# Disable repositoryItemCheckEdit after it's checked

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

I have a `repositoryItemCheckEdit` in a column of my grid. The task I want to do is :

#### Once the user pressed the `CheckEdit`  , this cell become disable so that the user can not make click again.

To do this task I'm using the `CheckedChanged` event, in the following way :

```
private void repositoryItemCheckEdit1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var obj = sender as CheckEdit;
     if (obj.Checked)
     {
        repositoryItemCheckEdit1.Enabled = false;                
     }
}
```

With the above event the only thing I get is that the cell becomes clearer , but not is disabled. Even if I make click again it allows me to do it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably have more luck/an easier time dealing with this using the brute force method... at least i find this a lot easier than dealing with the crazyness of DataGridView controls scheme.

Use the Tag attribute of your control to set a flag on it, and then when someone tries to un-check it/change it, force it back to checked. Like so:

```
private void repositoryItemCheckEdit1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var obj = sender as CheckEdit;
     if(obj.Tag != null)
     {
         obj.Checked = true;
         repositoryItemCheckEdit1.Enabled = false;
     }
     else
     {
         if (obj.Checked)
         {
            obj.Tag = true;
            repositoryItemCheckEdit1.Enabled = false;                
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Glad to have helped.